# Cassandra: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch: NoHostAvailable exception while inserting into table

Tags: cassandra, database-replication

I have created 2 node cassandra cluster with below configurations.
Node-1:
cassandra-topology.properties:

```
192.168.1.177=DC1:RAC1
192.168.1.134=DC2:RAC2
```

cassandra.yml:

```
cluster_name: 'TestCluster'
num_tokens: 256  
listen_address:  
rpc_address: localhost 
- seeds: "192.168.1.177,192.168.1.134"  
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Node-2:
cassandra-topology.properties:

```
192.168.1.177=DC1:RAC1  
127.0.0.1=DC2:RAC2 # Also tried 192.168.1.134 ip
```

cassandra.yml:

```
 cluster_name: 'TestCluster'  
    num_tokens: 256 
    listen_address:  
    rpc_address: localhost 
    - seeds: "192.168.1.177"  
    endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

I can see both the nodes are up and running using 'nodetool status' command. The Keyspace i have created is as below:

```
 > CREATE  KEYSPACE testReplication WITH replication = {'class':  NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : '2', 'DC2' : '2'};
```

I can also create tables which gets replicated to both the nodes, but when i try to 'INSERT' or 'SELECT' on the table cqlsh gives 'NoHostAvailable:',
but system.log is not showing anything about it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `cassandra.yaml` in each node, put your node ip to`rpc_address:` and `listen_address:` and try to put `seeds:` same for each node (DC1 and DC2). And also for `cassandra-topology.properties`, put the same configuration for each node. So, for example your Node-1 configuration will looks like:

```
cluster_name: 'TestCluster'
num_tokens: 256  
listen_address: 192.168.1.177
rpc_address: 192.168.1.177
- seeds: "192.168.1.177,192.168.1.134"  
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

And for each node, `cassandra-topology.properties`:

```
192.168.1.177=DC1:RAC1
192.168.1.134=DC2:RAC2
```

Comment: Followed your steps, still getting NoHostAvailable error, but this time `nodetool status` is showing only one node on both the machines.

Comment: The error you are having is the reason of your replication strategy. In DC1 and DC2 both, you have replication factor 2 but you have single node available in each DC. You need to have at least 2 node for replication factor 2. Usually we do replication factor 2, while 3 nodes available in a DC. But for 2 node DC, replication factory will work.